Serverless SQL Database and significant lag?
Long story short: I switched to Azure last month to use their SQL Database for a mobile app I'm testing (I'm the only tester). The iphone app is simple: I tap on the app in my iphone and it displays a list of rows that come from the Azure SQL database.
The initial list loaded incredibly fast (less than 2 seconds). Unfortunately, I had mistakenly selected the "Provisioned" Compute Tier at $350+/month.
So I went back to Azure and changed it to "Serverless", which starts at $4.78/month.
But now I've noticed that whenever I use the app after a reasonable amount of time without use, the list takes forever to load (if it loads). So for example, it's been 2 days since I last opened the app. I opened it just now and it took 15 seconds for the list to load. I opened it again and now it loads faster.
Since I'm the only tester, it seems that when I use it after an extended period of time, the database "wakes up".
Is the change to "Serverless" causing this lag?


Is the change to "Serverless" causing this lag?

Yes, almost undoubtedly. Cold starts are a well-known drawback to a serverless style architecture.
Microsoft documents this pretty ubiquitously in all documentation that specifically relates to their "serverless" service offerings. From the link above:

The latency to auto-resume and auto-pause a serverless database is generally order of 1 minute to auto-resume and 1-10 minutes after the expiration of the delay period to auto-pause.


This isn't directly related to the question, but is there a serverless option that doesn't have this latency?
